# How to interpret the ptp4l statistics in the ouput?

Tags: linux, clock, real-time

I get the following output from the `ptp4l` command on slave PTP node. When I terminate it, some global statistics are printed out, but I cannot interpret the values, as I do not find any evident correspondences with the values in the above output. To be precise, I know what the fields `offset`, `min`, `max` should be referring to in general, but:

1. why are there *pairs* of values instead of single values for each of those fields
2. what is `dev` actually? If it's the standard deviation "of something", what's the point in having the `min` and `max` subfields?
3. how are those pairs of values supposed to be computed or related to the above recordings?
4. can you explain the meaning of `drift`, especially?

**# ptp4l -p /dev/ptp0 -i eth0  -l 6 -m -s -2**

```
ptp4l[156535.175]: selected /dev/ptp0 as PTP clock
ptp4l[156535.179]: port 1: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[156535.181]: port 0: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[156535.183]:   version=2 ports=2
ptp4l[156535.184]:   access_delay=164000
ptp4l[156535.185]:   UTC offset: 37
ptp4l[156535.187]: port 1: link up
ptp4l[156536.340]: port 1: new foreign master 0010a1.fffe.9477ff-1
ptp4l[156540.354]: selected best master clock 0010a1.fffe.9477ff
ptp4l[156540.355]: port 1: LISTENING to UNCALIBRATED on RS_SLAVE
ptp4l[156541.044]: master offset    3199658 s0 freq   -3906 path delay         0
ptp4l[156542.055]: master offset    3199829 s3 freq   -3737 path delay         0
ptp4l[156543.066]: master offset    3199792 s1 freq   -3737 path delay        38
ptp4l[156544.077]: master offset         -8 s2 freq   -3739 path delay        38
ptp4l[156544.078]: port 1: UNCALIBRATED to SLAVE on MASTER_CLOCK_SELECTED
ptp4l[156545.088]: master offset        -25 s2 freq   -3752 path delay        40
ptp4l[156546.099]: master offset        -34 s2 freq   -3759 path delay        40
ptp4l[156547.110]: master offset        -43 s2 freq   -3768 path delay        41
ptp4l[156548.111]: master offset        -17 s2 freq   -3757 path delay        41
ptp4l[156549.122]: master offset        -19 s2 freq   -3759 path delay        39
ptp4l[156550.133]: master offset        -12 s2 freq   -3757 path delay        39
ptp4l[156551.144]: master offset         -7 s2 freq   -3755 path delay        40
ptp4l[156552.155]: master offset        -20 s2 freq   -3764 path delay        40
ptp4l[156553.166]: master offset         -9 s2 freq   -3759 path delay        40
ptp4l[156554.177]: master offset        -11 s2 freq   -3761 path delay        40
^C1=19:0 0:0
ptp4l[156554.674]:  
ptp4l[156554.674]: offset:
ptp4l[156554.674]: dev = 4.716450, -12.571429
ptp4l[156554.674]: min = 4.716450, 12.571429; max = 4.966555, 14.000000
ptp4l[156554.674]: dev:
ptp4l[156554.675]: dev = 1.903343, 3.305985
ptp4l[156554.675]: min = 1.903343, 2.691777; max = 1.959507, 3.305985
ptp4l[156554.675]: drift:
ptp4l[156554.675]: dev = 2.623987, -3758.795853
ptp4l[156554.675]: min = 2.623987, 3758.372996; max = 2.934894, 3758.795853
ptp4l[156554.676]: avg: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not see this in the regular build/executable. Could you share the version and which system you are running this.

ptp4l -v and anything than can help identify the exact repo/version.

Is it a switch or server? Looks like there are 2 ports / 2 NICs, so might be the two entries are for one-port each? Assuming that were the case, the O/P can actually be improved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).